# how does Keras flow_from_directory affect computer storage?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm trying to figure out the minimum amount of room I will need to train neural networks on my machine. Often times (image) data sets are relatively small in their raw forms, but when we transform them (in keras w/ flow_from_dir) we augment the images and kind of multiply the size of the data set to our desire.

My question is: how does flow_from_directory work with storing the augmented images? If I don't specify that the images need to be stored (parameter of the class) does keras augment the image, train with it and discard it or does it save it for a period of time, weighing down my computer until training is over?

Also, would those images be in persistent memory or RAM? Thank you in  advance.

Comment: flow_from directory is helpful when you cannot train model on your dataset keeping it in memory. it is like chunk of data is taken and stored in emmeory and then trained and discarded for fresh chunk

Comment: It sounds like it is stored in RAM then right? Is there any specific resource you are taking this form? @user5722540

Comment: I've found out information that may be helpful (and makes sense when you think about it.) Datasets of images (from Kaggle for example) contain relatively similar images, or images of the same type. This doesn't mean that they take up the same storage, however. I've found the range of storage these individual images in a data set take up is pretty big. After the augmentations in preprocessing the set of images that are augmented versions of the old ones have a *much* more predictable storage size.

Comment: This means that even if your initial dataset may be big, augmenting it and generating new data can be managed because of it's predictable nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, ImageDataGenerator does data augmentation on the fly and does not store the augmented images anywhere. As you mention, doing so would require too much space. So you should only worry about having enough RAM to fit a certain number of augmented batches, not the whole dataset.